# OpenVPN with Tor Issue in Linux Distros

Tags: 16.04, openvpn, tor

I'm trying to connect to an OpenVPN server trought Tor Socks Proxy, i have edited the .ovpn file adding socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 and socks-proxy-retry options but without success. In the specific the problem is the following: all go well and i see Initialization Sequence Completed but after some seconds openvpn client tries to reconnect so many times giving an error 115 timeout, I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04

Here is the log:

```
Sat Sep 17 00:55:07 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
Sat Sep 17 00:55:17 2016 [*.opengw.net] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Sat Sep 17 00:55:17 2016 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Sat Sep 17 00:55:17 2016 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Sat Sep 17 00:55:22 2016 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sat Sep 17 00:55:22 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Sat Sep 17 00:55:22 2016 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9050 [nonblock]
Sat Sep 17 00:55:22 2016 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9050
Sat Sep 17 00:55:27 2016 recv_socks_reply: TCP port read timeout expired: Operation now in progress (errno=115)
Sat Sep 17 00:55:27 2016 SIGUSR1[soft,init_instance] received, process restarting
Sat Sep 17 00:55:27 2016 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue on OpenVPN bugtracker: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/328
It seems TOR proxy is too slow and updating your OpenVPN client version to 2.4 might help.

Comment: how i can update openvpn client? I have installed it by apt-get install openvpn from official repo

Comment: Sadly, 2.4 still not released, so you need to get source code (they said that git master is 2.4 release so you can use their instructions on [their wiki](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/TesterDocumentation) to get it) and you must build it by yourself.

Comment: I can't find the 2.4 source to compile, can you give me a link?

Comment: To save your time on wiki reading ang git installing:
you can simply open https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn (it should open master branch by default), find there green button **Clone or download** and then in dropdown menu press *Download ZIP*

Comment: COMPILED BUT NOT WORKING... SAME PROBLEM...

Comment: maybe i will find a solution soon, i got an answer from an expert openvpn user that is following my problem at: http://superuser.com/questions/1125358/openvpn-with-tor-issue-in-linux-distros